# Linking to admin pages in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

So for a simple internally-used page I've gotta create an admin page, and I want to do it propperly.

I've got one problem with linking to said admin pages.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Blogposts",array('controller'=>'pages','action'=>'home')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Administration",array('controller'=>'blogposts','action'=>'index','admin'=>true)); ?>
```

So: the first link should always go to the main page with blogposts.
The second link should go to the administration area for said blogposts.

This works fine. But when I am in the admin area, and I click the top link again, it'll fail. It'll still prepend the "/admin/" path to the url.

When I add `'admin' => false` to the first link it works again, but I don't know if that is "best practice" or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is.  Any links in an admin area that you want to go to a non-admin area, should have `'admin'=>false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use custom routes you could also write your links this way:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Blogposts",'/pages/home'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link("Administration",'/admin/blogposts'); ?>
```

But if you want then to modify the URLs you can't use routes anymore.

Comment: Per your last sentence, writing links like that is NOT a goo idea.  Shouldn't recommend that to someone - especially someone who already understands the correct CakePHP -way of writing links.

Comment: IMHO, someone who does understand the way of writing links in Cake is someone who knows that different ways to do it exist. Then it is up to him to make the choice that best fits his needs. And that's why I didn't hide the downside of this method.